# What might cause a platform event to lose its subscription?

Tags: platform-event

We have a platform event in a clients org that has a trigger, but the subscription section is completely empty. So nothing is actually listening for this platform event, which is causing functionality issues.

I have seen a platform event go into Suspended status due to too many errors in the code the platform event runs through, but the subscription was still there, it just said 'Suspended' in the status section.

So I am curious as to how the subscription would just disappear? And is there any way to restore it in the clients org? For a suspended subscription, I know the way to resolve it was to make a change in the trigger and create a new package and then push that package to the org. Is that what is required here?

**This is a platform event from a managed package